# Select all tag instances by using getElementsByTagName() ? (tamper monkey)

Tags: javascript, dom, tampermonkey, userscripts, getelementsbytagname

- I am writing a JS, HTML, DOM script ( using Tamper Monkey ) for an ancient website.
- The idea is to use bootstrap and format some tables & lists.
- These tables, lists etc have no class, id or anything.
- So I grab it by tag name and add class name to it.
- I could only select 1 tag instance at a time.

Example

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className = 'list-group';
```

('ul')[0] gives first instence.

It does not work on just ('ul').

I want to grab every instance of ul at once.

note: I tried `document.querySelectorAll('ul').className = '';`

Not working. I want to give all ul same class name.

Comment: You can use ```for``` or ```forEach``` method on ```document.querySelectorAll('ul')``` .. Because  ```querySelectorAll``` returns array of HTML elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the result for `querySelectorAll` into an array and apply a `forEach` function on it:

```
const elementsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')
const elementsArray = Array.from(elementsCollection)
elementsArray.forEach(el => el.className = 'foo')
```

Or, if you want to use `querySelectorAll`:

```
const elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('ul')
elementsArray.forEach(el => el.className = 'foo')
```